# Starting Appium thorough bat file Windows

Tags: automation, appium

Hey guys I am using command prompt to start my appium server through command line. This is how my command looks like,

```
    "C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node.exe" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\bin\appium.js"
```

But the server starts on port 4723 which is default, what should I modify to start appium on custom port number like 4722 ?

Comment: because bootstrapport takes the portnumber 4723 which is already occupied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this and its working..
    "C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node.exe" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\bin\appium.js" --address 127.0.0.1 --port 4722 --no-reset --local-timezone

Answer (score 1):

You can get more details in [link](http://qahumor.blogspot.in/2016/08/appium-how-to-start-appium-server-using.html)

To do this, please follow the below steps:

Step 1: Make sure you have Node installed (if not, download it from link )  and would be good if you configured in your path variable, such that you can run node  from anywhere in your pc .It will be helpful in your automation.

Step 2: Make sure you have Appium server is installed.

Step 3 : Open Command Prompt and navigate to Appium folder till below path(based on your machine ,path may change)

#### C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules

Step 4: Now run below command, with Appium server argument which you think to be part of it, I have passed minimum argument, based on your requirement you can add more.

```
node appium --address 127.0.0.1 --port 4725 --platform-name Android --platform-version 19 --automation-name Appium
```

You can see Appium started at port 4725

Step 5:  Creating a batch file, this will make your life little easier in setup and running Appium script.
Open notepad and paste below code and save it as "appiumserver.bat"

```
REM ## START

echo "navigating to Appium folder"
REM ## change the folder path , based on your machine
cd /D C:/Appium/Appium/node_modules
node appium --address 127.0.0.1 --port 4725 --platform-name Android --platform-version 19 --automation-name Appium

REM ##END
```

Comment: This does not work anymore with appium v1.17. I'm getting error 
basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')")
          ^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution that works for me. In batch file, you can do like this:

```
cd /d "C:\Program Files\nodejs"
node "C:\Users\<YourUsername>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\build\lib\main.js"
```